# Exactly Copying a GET Request | Why Do I Get No Response?

Tags: rest, curl, get, burp

I have an app that makes GET requests to get some records from a database. I am trying to find out the GET request it makes so I don't have to keep going back to the app. I can simply make a curl request and get the data.

I installed the app on android studio's AVD and I intercepted the GET request using [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp):

Here's what the request looks like in Burp Suite:

```
GET [[Api end point and query parameters]] HTTP/1.1
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 14; sdk_gphone64_x86_64 Build/UPB3.230519.006)
Host: [[URL Hidden]]
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Other than the query parameters and the headers shown above, there are no cookies or body parameters, at least none that Burp Suite could show me. I formed a curl request

```
curl --trace-ascii - --location '[[URL:PORT]]/[[End Point And Query Params Exactly the Same as Above]]' --http1.1 \
--header "Accept-Charset: UTF-8" \
--header "User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 14; sdk_gphone64_x86_64 Build/UPB3.230519.006)" \
--header "Host: [[URL Hidden]]" \
--header "Connection: close" \
--header "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
```

For this I do not get a response back. It takes some time and the output is this

```
== Info:   Trying [IP Hidden]:433...
== Info: connect to [IP Hidden] port 433 failed: Connection timed out
== Info: Failed to connect to [URL Hidden] port 433 after 129511 ms: Couldn't connect to server
== Info: Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to [URL Hidden] port 433 after 129511 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Is there something I'm missing? I don't see any authorisation tokens or anything like that.